# ocultar o mostrar un input en una tabla en React segun seleccion de un Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

en un componente en React tengo una tabla, donde cada fila contiene el nombre de una materia; en la siguiente columna un Select con REGULAR y PROMOCIÓN como opciones; en la siguiente calif (que es un input) y en la ultima libro.
Si se selecciona PROMOCIÓN en el Select, en la columna o en el td perteneciente a Libro se debe exhibir un input.

Mi tabla es la siguiente:

```html
<table className="">
  <thead className="">
    <tr className="">
      <th className="">UNIDAD CURRICULAR</th>
      <th className="">ESTADO</th>
      <th className="">CALIF</th>
      <th>FOLIO</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody className="">
    {materias.map((m) => (
      <tr key={id} className="">
        <td className="">{m.materia}</td>
        <td className="">
          <Select
            options={options}
            placeholder="Estado"
            onChange={(e) =>
              handleEstado(e.value, e.label, m.id_materia, m.cuatrimestre)
            }
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            className=""
            onChange={(e) => handleCalif(e.target.value, m.id_materia)}
          />
        </td>

        <td>
          {
            <input
              type="number"
              className=""
              onChange={(e) => handleLibro(e.target.value, m.id_materia)}
            />
          }
        </td>
      </tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
</table>;
```

mi consulta es, como tengo el control de ocultar o exhibir el input que se encuentra en el td de libro, en cada fila de la tabla, ya que el usuario puede seleccionar REGULAR en una materia y por lo tanto no se deberia mostrar el input. Pero en otra materia puede seleccionar REGULAR y en este caso si debería mostrarse el input en la columna o en el td de libro

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo colocando una condición, ejemplo:

```
{(seleccion == "tuvalor") ? <input/> : null}
```